# Invalid overload for Label in RAZOR

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Error:Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Label' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.Label(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:

***Line 11:     *@Html.Label("Email", new { style = "width: 200px" })****

What i am doing : Applying CSS and styles to RAZOR in MVC since i'm beginner.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("register","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id="submitForm"})) 
{

   <div style="Width:200px">
    <i>@Html.Label("Name:", new { style = "width:200px;" })</i>
       @Html.TextBox("txtboxName")
   </div>
   <br />
   <div style="Width:200px">
    <i>@Html.Label("Email:")</i>
       @Html.TextBox("txtboxEmail")
   </div>
   <br />
   <div style="Width:200px">  
    <i>@Html.Label("Password:")</i>
       @Html.Password("txtboxPassword")
   </div>
   <br />
   <div>  
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
   </div>


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.Label`'s first argument is actually an expression as a string. It is essentially the same as `LabelFor` without the strongly-typed expression.

These expressions tell ASP.Net where to look for metadata. But in your case, you just want to output a literal string.

Therefore, you can simply say:

```
<label style="width:200px;">Name:</label>
```

If you did want to derive the value(s) from property metadata (which is often a good idea), you could construct a view model something like this:

```
// view model
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName( "An Email Address" )]
    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

// in your Razor view

@Html.LabelFor( o => o.Email, new { style = "width: 200px" } )
@Html.TextBoxFor( o => o.Email )
```

Note that with the aforementioned view model, you could now use the `Label` method. The first argument corresponds to the name of the property in the view model.

```
@Html.Label( "Email", new { style = "width: 200px" } )
```

Since this relies on a string it's more brittle than the previous example, but it answers your original question about using the overload properly.

---

Out of curiousity, I went through the MVC source to see how label expressions are handled. The first string argument of `Label` is definitely intended to be used as an expression (not a literal), but the framework will treat it as a string if an expression can't be derived.

In other words, in some cases your code would actually work, but this is internal behavior which could change and shouldn't be relied upon.

However, the fact that you received an error may indicate another problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: great. Awesome but i have t2o questions that why i can't get it working and 2nd that what i'm getting from GET SET in this example since it doesn't have anything to show or send.

Comment: 1) Not sure why you can't get it working. Can you post the stack trace you receive? 2) The view model can be used to generate form fields, and then when the form is submitted, the view model is created and data from the request is automatically set on the object. It's a powerful feature of MVC called "model binding". These articles may be usefl: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation and http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: check now, added more

Comment: That's odd...the overload is definitely there in MVC 4 and 5. What version of MVC are you running?

Comment: MVC 3 actually, could that be the reason ?

Comment: so there must be some way to get around this CSS thing in MVC 3 too, it's kinda impossible that they would have not included it in 3 :/

Comment: It may have been there in 3 as well...I don't recall. The simplest solution is just to create the label/style you want in HTML (my first example). The HTML helper methods don't provide any value in this case.

Comment: check this plz
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/XcX9021112-Inline-CSS-and-Styles-with-Html-Helpers-in-MVC3-Razor.html